# How can I combine the WCF services config for both http and https in one web.config?

Tags: web-config, wcf, wcf-binding

I spent a lot of time figuring out how to configure my WCF services so that they would work for https in the production environment.

Basically, I needed to do this:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" bindingNamespace="https://secure.mydomain.com" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpsBinding" contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HttpsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Adding the `bindingNamespace` attribute to the endpoint is the final thing that made it work.

But this config doesn't work in my local dev environment where I'm working under regular http.  So my config there is:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

The differences here are that I've set the `httpsGetEnabled` attribute to false, and I removed the bindingConfiguration and bindingNamespace.

The problem is: **how do I create one config block that handles BOTH?**

I really hate having to make lots of special modifications to the config every time I do a release.  Yes, I know I could have a post-build task that automatically changes the values, but I'd like to merge the configs if possible.

I tried something like this:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"/>
    <endpoint address="" bindingNamespace="https://secure.mydomain.com" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpsBinding" contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HttpsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I figured that putting both endpoints would give it two options to look for when activating the service.  However, this doesn't work.  I get this error:

**Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].**

From looking around SO and the rest of the internet, it appears that others have had problems slaying this dragon.

Comment: Are you hosting your WCF service in IIS, or are you self-hosting??

Comment: They are being hosted as .svc files in an ASP.NET web application.  Using IIS7 on both dev and prod.

Comment: @Cristi no, I had to keep the configs different between dev and prod.  In the past few years, I've moved away from WCF pretty much everywhere so the problem became obsolete (for me at least).

Comment: Actually it worked in the end for me. The issue was that I had no http binding set in IIS (removed it during some tests and forgot).

Answer (score 23):

Well, one problem with your combined config is that your two endpoints are on the same address - that won't work.

If you're hosting in IIS, then your server, virtual directory and the *.svc file needed will determine your basic address - it'll be something like:

```
http://yourservername/VirtualDirectory/YourService.svc
```

If you want to have two endpoints, at least one of them needs to define a relative address:

```
<services>
    <service name="MyNamespace.MyService" 
             behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
       <endpoint 
           address="basic" 
           binding="basicHttpBinding" 
           contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"/>
       <endpoint 
           address="secure" 
           binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpsBinding"  
           contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

In this case, you'd have your HTTP endpoint on:

```
http://yourservername/VirtualDirectory/YourService.svc/basic
```

and your secure HTTPS endpoint on:

```
https://yourservername/VirtualDirectory/YourService.svc/secure
```

Furthermore: your secure endpoint uses a `HttpsBinding` configuration - but you're lacking such a binding configuration - all you have is:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HttpBinding">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

You need to add the `HttpsBinding` configuration!!

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HttpBinding">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="HttpsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Sorry for the oversight, but I do actually have the secure binding.  If you look at my top config - the one on the server - it has the HttpsBinding in place.  That combined code I posted was manually curated by me in between when creating the SO question.

Comment: If I understand how the endpoint addresses work, adding those relative locations would change where the URL is accessed.  I want to use the same URL in both dev and prod.  So I don't want to have to add "basic" or "secure" on the end just because I switched to https.  Are you saying it's not possible otherwise?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for enabling HTTP/HTTPS on the same endpoint? I'm in the same situation - essentially I'm looking to change the securityMode value in the binding config based on the current request scheme in code

Comment: Here is an example how to have the same URL for secure and non-secure endpoints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797802/deploying-wcf-service-with-both-http-and-https-bindings-endpoints

Comment: This answer actually work. For one address, just remove the address field or define the same address for the endpoint.

Comment: I have this _bindings_ (`(type:hostname:port)`) in IIS: ***http:none hostaname:49759***, ***https:pre.company.es:443*** and ***http:pre.company.es:80***, what's about endpoint address ? I get `Could not find a base address ...` error or `404 not found` for my svc, according my _servicemodel configuration_.
I have problems about ***baseaddress***: _http://preserver:49759/vdir1/SilverlightServices/serv.svc_ and _https://pre.company.es/vdir1/SilverlightServices/serv.svc_

Comment: At the time this post was written, having the service running via http and https required two endpoints.  At some point, this issue has been patched and both http and https can be served from the same endpoint.

Answer (score 8):

I recently had to make a WCF 3.5 REST (`webHttpBinding`) service available on both HTTP and HTTPS in a Microsoft Azure App Service (IIS). It was a fun... and agonizing adventure. Here are my findings and my `web.config`'s `<system.serviceModel>`:

**Note:** these notes are for a WCF REST web-service running using `*.svc` (`@ServiceHost`) files within a minimal ASP.NET 4.7 application (with `Global.asax`) within IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016. These notes **do not** apply to self-hosted WCF services, non-REST WCF services (i.e. SOAP), or platforms older than .NET Framework 4.7. This also does not apply to .NET Core.

- Upgrade to .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later (that's just common-sense)
- **The most important part** is using the `<serviceHostingEnvironment>` element is essential, ensure that `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"` is set.

  - This is documented here:

    - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/supporting-multiple-iis-site-bindings
    - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/servicehostingenvironment
  - It looks like this was added in .NET Framework 4.0 ( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saurabs/2012/11/21/wcf-handling-multiple-iis-bindings/ ), in .NET 3.5 you needed to use `<baseAddressPrefixFilters>` which are not necessary anymore.
- You **do not** need the `<serviceMetadata>` element in your `web.config` file at all.

  - Apparently this element is for WSDL metadata - and RESTful services do not support WSDL.
  - I point this out because there's at least a few top Google search results for articles and StackOverflow postings where people say this is required. Those people are incorrect.
- **Do not** use absolute URIs in your `<endpoint address=""` attributes - just leave the attribute empty.

  - This was only necessary in WCF 3.5.
  - Microsoft says to leave it blank (or use a relative URI for `PATH_INFO`-style endpoints) when hosting WCF in IIS:

    - Read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/deploying-an-internet-information-services-hosted-wcf-service

      > You must always use relative endpoint addresses for IIS-hosted service endpoints. Supplying a fully-qualified endpoint address (for example, http://localhost/MyService.svc) can lead to errors in the deployment of the service if the endpoint address does not point to the IIS-application that hosts the service exposing the endpoint. Using relative endpoint addresses for hosted services avoids these potential conflicts.
- WCF will detect if it can be reached using both HTTP and HTTPS and will raise an error if the `web.config` file tells WCF to accept HTTPS connections when the hosting application (i.e. IIS) does not have HTTPS enabled in its parent website.

  - This was unexpected to me because all other web-application platforms I've used don't complain if they're configured for HTTPS but the parent webserver isn't.

    - Especially given that in this case, WCF runs with/inside the .NET request pipeline and ASP.NET certainly doesn't care about IIS' Website Binding (because ASP.NET is designed to be agnostic about parent Website bindings)
    - Note: "website bindings" refers to IIS Website Bindings, **not** "WCF bindings" which are a separate concept.
- To get this working locally in Visual Studio and IIS Express, ensure that the parent Web Application Project has "SSL Enabled = True" in the "Properties" window (not the same thing as the "Project Properties" window (yes, I screamed too):

  - [image]
- In .NET 4.6.1, Microsoft simplified WCF's configuration by allowing the `<services>` element to be omitted and be automatically generated behind-the-scenes, however I didn't have consistent results with RESTful services with dual-HTTP+HTTPS bindings, so I still specify my `<services>` manually.

  - This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/simplified-configuration

### TL;DR:

Here's my `<system.serviceModel>` element from my `web.config` file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfService1.MainService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IMainService" behaviorConfiguration="myWebBehavior" bindingConfiguration="myWebHttpBindingInsecure" />
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IMainService" behaviorConfiguration="myWebBehavior" bindingConfiguration="myWebHttpBindingSecure" />
        </service>
        <service name="WcfService1.AnotherService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IAnotherService" behaviorConfiguration="myWebBehavior" bindingConfiguration="myWebHttpBindingInsecure" />
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IAnotherService" behaviorConfiguration="myWebBehavior" bindingConfiguration="myWebHttpBindingSecure" />
        </service>
        <!--  etc... -->
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="myWebBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <!-- By default (in machine.config), the 'http' scheme is mapped to 'basicHttpBinding' (SOAP), not 'webHttpBinding' (REST) and the 'https' scheme is not mapped. -->
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="myWebHttpBindingSecure" />
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"  bindingConfiguration="myWebHttpBindingInsecure" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <!-- maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" is 100MiB -->
            <binding name="myWebHttpBindingInsecure" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" transferMode="Streamed">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="myWebHttpBindingSecure" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" transferMode="Streamed">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with the config file but with the IIS setup.
You need to enable both HTTP & HTTPS in IIS.
In IIS 7.5, go to your site and click on Bindings under Edit Site Action. Ensure that both http & https have been added.
Then you need to create a binding for HTTP under `<basicHttpBinding>`, with security mode set to none.
Add the newly created binding configuration to http endpoint.
You are good to go. Let me know if you need further issue.

Comment: My issue: _bindings_ (`(type:hostname:port)`) in IIS: ***http:none hostaname:49759***, ***https:pre.company.es:443*** and ***http:pre.company.es:80***, AND 
***baseaddress***: _http://preserver:49759/vdir1/SilverlightServices/serv.svc_ and _https://pre.company.es/vdir1/SilverlightServices/serv.svc_

Answer (score 0):

The solution for running in a local domain and also running on production and other environments, without relying on memory to change anything, is config transformations. They transform the compiled web.config based on the selected configuration profile. Locally I run in `Debug` mode, on the testing environment I [publish](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx) to a `TestRelease` profile, and production I have another profile:

[image: Web.Config Transforms in Visual Studio]

If you can't expand your web.config, you can right click and add config tranforms. In order to get more than Debug and Release, you add more configurations via the manager:

[image: Configuration Manager in Visual Studio]

Here's example transformations:

### Web.Debug.config

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--...-->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration">
          <security xdt:Transform="Remove">
            <transport xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="fileTransferBinding">
          <security xdt:Transform="Remove">
            <transport xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

### Web.Release.config

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--...-->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration">
          <security mode="Transport" xdt:Transform="Insert">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="fileTransferBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" xdt:Transform="Insert">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"  xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```