# Http and Https request to WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

In `system.service / behaviours / servicebehaviours`

I have the following behaviour:

```
<behavior name="pubajaxAspNetAjaxBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
```

With both these properties httpGetEnabled="true" and httpsGetEnabled="true" in place it means any requests to my webservice over http now throw the error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the
>   endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [http].

Is it possible to have a WCF service that accepts http and https requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can have them both true on the same endpoint, but you can use different bindings for different endpoints.

You can use bindings for that

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpBinding">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="HttpsBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Please look at that post

[Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346926/how-can-i-combine-the-wcf-services-config-for-both-http-and-https-in-one-web-conf)