# Web service different internal soap:address. How to call methods

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to call a web service method using c# and I get a response

> There was no endpoint listening at https://sub.example.com/Service/Services.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Inner exception as follows

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I am thinking that this is because of proxy or some other issue. When I add the reference using Visual Studio it will auto generate soap address to

> http://computername.local/Service/Service.svc

So the key problem is that service is available by different address externally but IIS responses are using internall address.

I have tried to call web service methods using different approaches binging connection to proxy address but it is no use. Is there a way to solve this or does the service provider need to make a change in the IIS configuration?

Config is as follows

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>


<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBindingConfiguration" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

When accessing site using http the service returns either IP or name, same as in the address bar. But when accessing using https service returns computer name.

Comment: The auto generated address starts with "http", but the address which you are trying to call your service starts with "https". These are different. Take look at " serviceBehaviors " section in web.config

Comment: I will update question and add these config sections

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the bindings are the reason why this is not working

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBindingConfiguration" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
  <security mode="None" />
</binding>
```

Security mode was wrong and it should be

> security mode="Transport"

If there is need to have http and https side bu side then there is need to add multiple bindings.

[How can I combine the WCF services config for both http and https in one web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346926/how-can-i-combine-the-wcf-services-config-for-both-http-and-https-in-one-web-con)